# How to select distinct from resultset using sqlalchemy core?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have 3 models: tasks, remarks, documents. A task can have 1/ more remarks  and/or documents. Models:

```
tasks = Table("tasks", metadata,
              Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True)

update_history = Table("update_history", metadata,
                   Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                   Column("remarks", String),
                   Column("task_id", Integer,ForeignKey("tasks.id")),

documents = Table("documents", metadata,
                  Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
                  Column("file_name", String),
                  Column("task_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tasks.id"))
```

Omitted other attributes. I am using sqlalchemy core **only** How do I generate a table remarks, documents for a particular task.

I tried:

```
tasks1 = tasks.alias()
s = select([tasks.c.description.distinct(),
            update_history.c.id.label('updates_id'),
            update_history.c.remarks,
            documents.c.file_name
            ]).\
    where(
          and_(
               tasks.c.id == task_id,
               update_history.c.task_id == task_id,
               documents.c.task_id == task_id
               )
          ).\
    select_from(update_history.
    join(tasks, update_history.c.task_id == tasks.c.id)).\
    select_from(documents.
    join(tasks1, documents.c.task_id == tasks1.c.id)
                )
```

For this I get multiple output, not distinct output i.e for the same task, if there are 2 remarks, 2 documents, my o/p should be just 1 distinct task id, with the distinct remarks, distinct document names. Currently I get:

```
{
  "updates_docs": [
    {
      "description": "Create journal entries for May 2015", 
      "file_name": "bower.txt", 
      "remarks": "remark 1 for task 1", 
      "updates_id": 1
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Create journal entries for May 2015", 
      "file_name": "curl_commands.md", 
      "remarks": "remark 2 for task 1", 
      "updates_id": 2
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Create journal entries for May 2015", 
      "file_name": "curl_commands.md", 
      "remarks": "remark 1 for task 1", 
      "updates_id": 1
    }, 
    {
      "description": "Create journal entries for May 2015", 
      "file_name": "bower.txt", 
      "remarks": "remark 2 for task 1", 
      "updates_id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

which is not desirable. Is there a better way to use distinct and sqlalchemy core expression language properly?
Using postgresql 9.1

Comment: Why are you joining `tasks` twice?

Comment: @dirn How do I do it exactly? I am still learning sqlalchemy